# React-native-maps Mapview Render

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, react-native, android-mapview

I'm using Mapview with React-Native (react-native-maps) on Android, and I got this :

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11644230/19089605/4fac71f4-8a7b-11e6-998d-9a41461b2c16.png

Problem is : I have "2 Maps rendered", one in front of which can't moove and another "small" on the top of the screen which is working... (in the background)
As you can see on my picture, the fix map is on San Francisco and the other small one mooved to Green Valley ...

Do you know how I can fix this ?

Here is my javascript file :

```
// Fonction qui récupère la position actuelle de l'utilisateur
getCurrrentPosition() {
    // Permet de vérifier que la fonction s'exécute bien que lorsqu'on clique sur le bouton "get position"
    //console.log("execute");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            var current_position = JSON.stringify(position);
            // C'est comme ça qu'on récupère la lattitude et la longitude car positon corresponds à un json (affiché dans current_position)
            //console.log("lattitude "+position.coords.latitude);

            // On set les différents state récupérés avec la position...
            this.setState({current_position});
            this.setState({latitude:position.coords.latitude});
            this.setState({longitude:position.coords.longitude});

        },
        (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
}


render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text> Geolocalisation: </Text>
            <Text>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Position actuelle: </Text>
                {this.state.current_position}
            </Text>
            {/*Bouton qui récupère la position*/}
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>  this.getCurrrentPosition()} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get current position </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            {/*Affichage de la lattitude et de la longitude*/}
            <Text>Latitude : {this.state.latitude}</Text>
            <Text>Longitude : {this.state.longitude}</Text>
            <MapView  style={styles.container}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 37.78825,
                    longitude: -122.4324,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
            />


        </View>
    )
}
```

}

// here my StyleSheet (except container)

```
map: {
},
welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
},
navigator: {
    flex: 1,
},
scrollView: {
    marginTop: 64
},
row: {
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
    borderBottomColor: '#CDCDCD',
},
rowText: {
    fontSize: 17,
},
button: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderColor: 'blue',
},
    buttonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500',
        color:'white',
},
```

Thanks a lot for your help !